# What is the safest cross-platform way to get the address of a byte in a word?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, platform-agnostic

The following sets `byte` to 1 on big-endian and 0 on little-endian.

```
uint16_t word = 0x0001;
uint8_t byte = *(((uint8_t *)&word) + 1);
```

Is there any way to get the address of the low or high byte that is cross-platform safe?

Comment: Do you really want the address or would some [bit manipulation](https://godbolt.org/z/8cz651E7a) be fine too?

Comment: Yep, was just curious if it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C99, code could use a *compound literal* to find the MSByte address offset.
Let the compiler form efficient code.

Below uses a 4-byte example to help illustrate adherence with big, little and [PDP endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#PDP-endian).

```
int main() {
  uint32_t word = 0x12345678;
  printf("%p\n", (void*)&word);
  for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof word; i++) printf("%x\n", ((uint8_t*) &word)[i]);

  uint8_t *msbyte_address = ((uint8_t*) &word) + //
  //  v----------------------------------------------------v compound literal
      ( union { uint32_t u32; uint8_t u8[4]; }) {0x00010203}.u8[0];
  //                                    value at 1st byte    ^---^

  printf("%p\n", (void*)msbyte_address);
}
```

Example output (little endian)

```
0xffffcbfc
78
56
34
12
0xffffcbff
```

---

For `uint16_t`

```
  uint16_t word = 0x1234;
  uint8_t *msbyte_address = ((uint8_t*) &word) + 
      ( union { uint16_t u16; uint8_t u8[2]; }) {0x0001}.u8[0];
```

Comment: I was so close!  Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
int isBigEndian()
{
    uint16_t word = 0x0001;
    return *(((uint8_t *)&word) + 1);
}

void main()
{
    uint16_t word = 0x0001;
    uint8_t byte = *(((uint8_t *)&word) + isBigEndian());
    printf("%d\n", byte);
}
```

To avoid checking at run time everytime, you can use a `#define` and verify it is a correct assumption using `assert`. Like this:

```
#define BIG_ENDIAN 0  // 0 or 1 depending on what the platform is

void main()
{
    assert(isBigEndian() == BIG_ENDIAN);  // Make sure #define is OK
    // more code...
}
```

Elsewhere in the code, you use the symbol `BIG_ENDIAN` to compile code depending on the platform. So there is no other actual check than the `assert`.

Comment: Yep but I was hoping for something in the language.

Comment: If your `int isBigEndian(void)` body is available (/if it is inlinable), compilers like gcc and clang won't generate runtime code for it.